# C++ std::swap - Does it swap data or data pointers?

Tags: c++, ole, bstr

I'm using `std::swap` with OLE `BSTR`s.

I would like to confirm that this function swaps the data pointers and not the strings themselves.

Is this the case?

Comment: `BSTR` is a typedef for `wchar_t*`. Yes, when called with two `BSTR`s, `std::swap` would just swap two pointers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you. I'll accept your answer if you type it up.

Comment: What/how `std::swap()` swaps depends on the type of the given arguments. There are numerous overloads for specific types when a more efficient solution is possible than the naive `tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;`.

Comment: @Scheff And with two `BSTR`s as arguments?

Comment: Assuming that `BSTR` is in fact `wchar_t*` like mentioned by @Igor, I would bet for a trivial/naive swap. I checked how a real compiler might do it. [Test in CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/W7cr6e). g++ 9.2 is very clever. It recognized the `std::swap()` as no-op (if the meanings of `p1` and `p2` are "swapped" after the call of `std::swap()`), and just optimized it out. That's surely the most efficient  implementation of `std::swap()`... ;-) (Before, I consulted [std::swap()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) whether there is a specialization for pointer but it isn't.)